# psycopg2 execute syntax error with insert?

Tags: psycopg2

I try to insert data in a table with psycopg2 but I have an exception. I think a problem occurs with execute() syntax but I don't find what's wrong. Could you help me please? Thank you!

```
import psycopg2
import logging
from datetime import datetime

db_host = '##'
db_port = '##'
db_name = '##'
db_user = '##'
db_password = '##'

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(host = db_host, port = db_port, dbname = db_name, user = db_user, password = db_password)
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    def load():
        select_query = "SELECT id_inter::text AS code, to_timestamp(dh_inter,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')::timestamp without time zone AS dh, id_rs::text AS nature, geom FROM dnp.inf_inter WHERE id_rs SIMILAR TO ('I1310%|1310%')"
        cursor.execute(select_query)
        
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        
        for row in rows:
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO iff.inter_i1310 (code, dh, nature, geom) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON CONFLICT (code) DO NOTHING"
            cursor.execute(insert_query, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))
        
        connection.commit()
    
    load()

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print('KO')

finally:
    if connection in locals() or connection in globals():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.